# ouput is printing both if cases [java]

Tags: java, sum

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to make something that if the arg[0] is 0, prints the number of additonal arguments, and if the arg[0] is 1, adds up the total of the additional arguments. e.g

```
java Summo 0 3 5 6

2
```

and:

```
java Summo 1 2 3

5.0
```

I seem to have got it somewhat working, it can get the answers, but for some reason when I do the 0 case, it prints the answer, then a new line of 0.0.

```
public class Summo
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
  int K = Integer.parseInt(args [0]);
  float [] a = new float [args.length-1];
  for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) 
      a[i-1] = Float.parseFloat(args [i]);
  float sum = 0.0f;
  if (K == 0)
      System.out.println (a.length);


  if (K == 1)
      for (float i: a)
           sum += i;
  System.out.println(sum);
  }
}
```

Comment: Use curly braces to represent a block of code and avoid unnecessary confusion.

Comment: You should use curly brackets for your `for`s and `if`s. The final print statement is being executed because `if (K == 1)` only contains the for loop below it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have block issues.

```
if (K == 1)
    for (float i: a)
      sum += i;
    System.out.println(sum);
```

should be

```
if (K == 1)
{
    for (float i: a)
      sum += i;
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

If you ommit the curly braces `{}`, only first instruction is executed inside the `if` block, i.e. `for` loop is executed only if `k == 1`, but `println` method is executed always.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the following code

from

```
if (K == 1)
  for (float i: a)
       sum += i;
 System.out.println(sum);
```

Note: In your code 'System.out.println(sum);' will always be executed. If K=0, since sum is 0.0f. That's why extra 0.0 is printed in console.

to

```
    if (K == 1) {
        for (float i : a)
            sum += i;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
```